# Countdown Timer in Vanilla Javascript without using a function

Tags: javascript, countdown

I have a project where I need to do a countdown timer, However no function can be used. I know that this can be done with a setInterval, however, most of the documentation I have found shows a function being used in conjunction. W3schools has a great example, however, it used a function. I know how I would do it with

I have already written some code, and was able to display the minutes and seconds, however, cannot get it to actually count down. is there a way to do this without a function?

```
const timeSpan = document.getElementById('timer');

// Get Time Now
var timeMinutes = 10;
var currentTime = Date.parse(new Date());
var deadline = new Date(currentTime + timeMinutes * 60 * 1000);
var distance = deadline - currentTime;
var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

timeSpan.innerHTML = minutes + 's' + seconds;
```

This shows the minutes and seconds, but without the setInterval or setTimeOut it wont count down like a normal countdown timer. For the project it needs to count down from ten minutes and at the end alert the user that is is expired and that they will need to refresh the page.

Comment: "no function can be used" what does this mean? Your example uses a bunch of functions (e.g. Math.floor, Date.parse, Date.constructor, document.getElementById).

Comment: `setInterval` is a function, it also takes a function to call every time it 'ticks'. You can't do this without functions.

Comment: Is this a school assignment? Maybe post the exact question? I think maybe you mean you can't use `setInterval`?

Comment: Ah, Im sorry I should have been more clear (and to be honest I did not know that there was more functions then just the `function()` code). I would need it to not be called in a `function()` tag, but instead be called ondocumentload. does that make more sense? The exact wording is "1. JavaScript code outside of any functions (Don’t put this functionality within a JavaScript function:"

Comment: OK, so you can't create your own function, but you can use existing ones, correct?

Comment: Yes, That is correct. @Josh Noe

Comment: But the syntax of `setInterval` still requires a `function`.

Comment: let me confirm with the instructor on what this means exactly. Because I thought about the same problem over and over, and I do not see that there is a way of doing this without using `function` or the arrow dealio.

Comment: A javascript learning task where you can't use functions is like a writing task where you can't use letters. You can quote me on that.

Comment: I would think your instructor meant to say, don't use any in-built javascript functions, and write your own code, ie don't use setInterval

Comment: well, theoretically, you could use the obsolete form `setTimeout('your code here')`, but this would be totally lame.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to move some things out of the function as you are resetting the timer on every interval. You should avoid storing your times as Date objects as well since you only need the timestamps.

```js
const timeSpan = document.getElementById('timer');

const mins = 10;
const now = new Date().getTime();
const deadline = mins * 60 * 1000 + now;


setInterval(() => {
  var currentTime = new Date().getTime();
  var distance = deadline - currentTime;
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  timeSpan.innerHTML = minutes + 's' + seconds;
}, 500)
```

```html
<span id=timer></span>
```

Comment: I appreciate the help for sure, I have asked the instructor to clarify the instructions to ensure that I can use this. This is what I had the idea to do, but because it was using the arrow function I am not sure if it is allowed. Alas, it doesnt seem to be possible without using some type of function.

Comment: based on what you've told us it sounds like he just wants procedural code. javascript doesnt have a goto command so either use a function or refresh the entire page every second are your only option.s

Answer (score -1):

```
<script>    
var timer   = (mins) => {
                        
    const timeSpan  = document.getElementById('timer');
    const now       = new Date().getTime();
    const deadline  = mins * 60 * 1000 + now;
    
    setInterval(() => {
        var currentTime = new Date().getTime();
        var distance = deadline - currentTime;
        var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
        var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    
                                
        timeSpan.innerHTML = minutes + ' min. ' + seconds + ' s.';
        
        if (minutes <=0 && seconds <=0) {
                alert('Time is over');
                return false;
        }

    }, 1000);   
 }
 
 timer(10);

</script>
<span id="timer"></span>
```